# Change Feed in multi-region Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Cosmos DB multi-region (single region write) account. Currently it is enabled in East US and West US. The write region is West US.

The Change Feed listeners are deployed in both East US and West US. I wanted to understand, if I can specify that the listeners deployed in East US reads Change Feed from East US and listeners in West US reads Change Feed from West US. Or all the listeners will always read Change Feed from write region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly make your listeners read from the closest region, which should improve your latency. You can use the [PreferredLocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.preferredlocations?view=azure-dotnet#remarks) attribute to customize that:

```
var localPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();
localPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add("East US");

// Builder initialization
.WithFeedCollection(new DocumentCollectionInfo()
{
    DatabaseName = DbName,
    Uri = new Uri(uri),
    CollectionName = feedCollection,
    MasterKey = key,
    ConnectionPolicy = localPolicy
})
.BuildAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One follow up question here, do I need to set similar policy for Lease collection also or I should always use the write region for the Lease collection. 

I am using change feed processor library and as per my understanding, there will be both read and write operations on Lease collection while there will only be reads from Feed collection.

Comment: Lease collection can be in a different and separate account, and you can customize a PreferredLocations for it too that could be the same or not. Keep in mind that since Lease Collection will do write and reads, on a single master account, you don't have much choice, it's always to the Write regiong. On a Multi Master account though, it does give more flexibility as it can write to any region.